# The map $\left(\frac{.}{p}\right):=\mathbb F_p \rightarrow [\pm1]$ taking $a\in \mathbb F_p$ to $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ is homomorphism

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, group-homomorphism, legendre-symbol

> Prove that the map $\left(\frac{.}{p}\right):=\mathbb F_p \rightarrow [\pm1]$ taking $a\in \mathbb F_p$ to $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ is a
>   homomorphism

I don't know how to even start this problem. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: There are three things to show: the product of two quadratic residues is a quadratic residue, the product of two non-residues is a residue, and the product of a residue and a non-residue is a non-residue.

Comment: @Slade Ok thank you, that really helps

Comment: The Legendre symbol is simply the Character of the group corresponding to -1 i.e. a map from the field to a subset of roots of 1.